# Laptop automatically connected to new router/hotspot (WI-FI)

Tags: wireless-networking, router, netgear-router

I installed a new router/hotspot. I choose the same name and password as I used at the old router/hotspot. Now when I started my Laptop I was automatically connected (WI-FI) with the new router without any request to type in the password.

I switched from a `NETGEAR Aircard 790S Mobile Hotspot` to the `NETGEAR Hotspot Nighthawk M1`. I don't  know the encryption protocol from the first router/hotspot, but on the new one I have `WPA2_Personal_AES`

How is this possible?

How isn’t this a security issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wifi association happens based on the SSID (Wifi network name) and passphrase (Wifi password) used. The device does not matter in your situation. You can configure as many Wifi Access Points that use the same SSID and Passphrase as you want, and your Wifi client will automatically roam to the closest one. This is by design and not a security issue. Your computer does not care that the Wifi device changed, as long as it can authenticate to an available SSID with the passphrase you provided.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know the _method or technique_ that make this possible? @JimDiroffII

Comment: Because you preconfigured your new wifi network with a previously known Wifi network SSID and passphrase that your computer had already saved. Once the PC saw a Wifi radio with the preconfigured SSID, it tried to authenticate with its known passphrase, and was successful. I hope that helps answer your question. This document from Cisco goes over wifi authentication methods and how they function: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/wireless/software/guide/SecurityAuthenticationTypes.html